# hierarchyID GetAncestor as ID

Tags: parsing, sql-server-2012, hierarchyid

Problem: I need to extrapolate the parentID from the hierarchyID.

Example: My columnID is 8 and my current hierarchyID is  `/1/2/4/8`. When I call  `columnName.GetAncestor(1)`, this will give me `/1/2/4/`. What I need is the ID of `4`.

**How do I do this? Or are hierarchyIDs only meant to be joined on?**

I'm looking into the [SqlHierarchyID.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677201.aspx) but I'm not understanding how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get another field value for the GetAncestor(1) hierarchyid you need to do an inner join like this:

```
SELECT A.hid, A.myid, B.hid, B.myid 
FROM dbo.mytable A
INNER JOIN dbo.mytable B ON A.hid.GetAncestor(1) = B.hid
```

This returns each row with its parent in the same row (will probably miss the root row, though, but if you add a WHERE clause to get the hid you're interested in, then this should suffice).